# Magento2 Product image not getting displayed in search result & cart page

Tags: product-images, magento2.4.2, magento-cloud

Magento2.4.2 Cloud. I uploaded a product image from Admin for 1 product, but the issue is that the image gets displayed on the product details page & mini-cart, but it is not getting displayed on the cart page & product search result.

Please someone can guide me on what steps to follow.

Comment: If it is not getting displayed on cart/product search page, check the image urls getting generated on both of this pages and compare it with the PDP/minicart image urls.

Comment: @RahulBarot I verified both are same

Comment: Also for local setup it is working, issue is only in cloud setup

Comment: can you share reference url of the site for further checking. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Run below command one time and check it. It's get some time for completion.

```
php bin/magento catalog:images:resize
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check image **Role**.

Make sure your Image assigned to "base","small", "thumbnail".

[image]

Comment: that is all selected.

Comment: If you are using custom theme then change default theme to luma or blank and check on frontend